# Sharing an actor among other actors

Tags: akka, actor

I have a AKKA model that there is a Supervisor actor which creates many child actors. child actors will process an event and send the message to another service (e.g Kafka topic).

Currently I have a static shared class that is shared among child actors for sending out messages, but in Actor model I think it is better to use an actor for this purpose.

I want to know how can I create an actor that child actors can share it. If supervisor actor creates MessagePublisher actor, can children find an send the message to it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case you can either create the shared `Actor` at top level or as a child `Actor` to your supervisor.
Then you just pass the `ActorRef` either using a message or the constructor to the supervisor / child actors and keep it as `Actor` internal state.

The following code should illustrate it (It's Scala but it should be pretty easy to translate it to Java).

```
package test

import akka.actor.Actor.Receive
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object TestClass extends App {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem( "ActorSystem" )

    implicit val executor = system.dispatcher

    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer( )

    //Option 1 Create as top level actor and pass to supervisor with init message
    val sharedActor: ActorRef = system.actorOf( Props[ SharedActor ] )

    val supervisor: ActorRef = system.actorOf( Props[ SupervisorActor ] )
    supervisor ! InitWithSharedActor( sharedActor )

    supervisor ! "NoArgsChild"
    supervisor ! "ArgsChild"

    class SupervisorActor extends Actor {
            private var sharedActor: Option[ ActorRef ] = None

            override def preStart( ) = {
                    //Option 2 Init as child actor of supervisor
                    println( "Start Supervisor" )
                    sharedActor = Some( context.actorOf( Props[ SharedActor ] ) )
            }

            override def receive: Receive = {
                    case InitWithSharedActor( sa ) =>
                            sharedActor = Some( sa )
                    case "NoArgsChild" =>
                            //Pass to child actor in init msg
                            sharedActor.foreach( sa => context.actorOf( Props[ ChildActor ] ) ! InitWithSharedActor( sa ) )
                    case "ArgsChild" =>
                            //Pass to child with constructor
                            sharedActor.foreach( sa => context.actorOf( Props( new ChildActorWithArgs( sa ) ) ) )
            }
    }

    class SharedActor extends Actor {

            override def preStart( ) = {
                    println( "Start Shared Actor" )
            }

            override def receive: Receive = {
                    case _ =>
            }
    }

    class ChildActor extends Actor {
            private var sharedActor: Option[ ActorRef ] = None

            override def preStart( ) = {
                    println( "Start NoArg Child Actor" )
            }

            override def receive: Receive = {
                    case InitWithSharedActor( sa ) => sharedActor = Some( sa )
            }
    }

    class ChildActorWithArgs( sharedActor: ActorRef ) extends Actor {

            override def preStart( ) = {
                    println( "Start WithArg Child Actor" )
            }

            override def receive: Receive = {
                    case _ =>
            }
    }

    case class InitWithSharedActor( sharedActor: ActorRef )

}
```